# not able to create sym-link our OpenCV cv2.so bindings into cv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

(cv) dell@dell-Inspiron-3442:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

(cv) dell@dell-Inspiron-3442:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so

ln: failed to create symbolic link 'cv2.so': File exists

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the arguments flipped like so:

```
ln -s cv2.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Answer (score 0):

It says *File exists.* If you do a `ls` command you would see there is already a *cv2.so* file in this directory. Remove the existing *cv2.so* file under the current directory (`~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`) and run your `ln` command again:

`rm cv2.so`

`ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so`